# Parse csv file and generate graphs in HTML file using C#

Tags: c#

I want to parse one csv file and generate the charts/graphs in the html file. 
I have worked with Microsoft Charts for Win Form Apps but dint find a way to extract/export them to HTML file.
Can anyone help me with that?

thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you mean you have convert csv to MS Excel chart, and now you want to export the chart to Html? Do i got you right?

Comment: I think chart has a `SaveImage` method, you can get those images and then show them in `<img` tags

Comment: @george: I have on CSV File and I want to prepare the charts using it and show them in an HTML.

Comment: @V4Vendetta: thanks. currently am doing this way only.. :) looking for better options..

Comment: @user1283104 well you can also have an handler which could process it and return the image to the `Response` stream but then its not really pure html way

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, Microsoft charting doesn't let you export the charts to HTML. You can export them as an image (jpeg or gif) then embed that in a HTML page, but HTML tags alone won't be able to represent the image the graph produces.

Comment: Cool, will watch this to see if you find a better way. I don't think there is any other option. Scalable Vector Graphics or SVG might be worth looking into.

Comment: thanks for the help... btw previously I dint mean to discourage your last point. apologies if my poor english made it mean like that. and will surely look in SVG..